# Messagefilter dropped 100% of messages

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, ros-kinetic, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When launching the navigation stack (gmapping and movebase) I will frequently receive the following message:

```
[ WARN] [1477990695.164889638]: MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.costmap_2d.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
[ WARN] [1477990695.175311684]: MessageFilter [target=map ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.costmap_2d.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
```

When looking at my tf tree i see the following information.
[image description http://i68.tinypic.com/2s7e0lz.png](http://i68.tinypic.com/2s7e0lz.png)

I will update this post with rosconsole logger to debug information soon.
The following message is given:

```
[DEBUG] [1299740216.768663556, 1299651571.155978846]: MessageFilter [target=/odom ]: Removed oldest message because buffer is full, count now 5 (frame_id=camera_depth_frame, stamp=1299651570.618031)

[DEBUG] [1299740216.768820286, 1299651571.155978846]: MessageFilter [target=/odom ]: Added message in frame laser at time 1299651571.154, count now 5
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246928/messagefilter-dropped-100%-of-messages/) by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2016-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem can be found in the debug.
It is in frame_id=camera_depth_frame. I came to this conclusion thanks to this post: [gmapping-works-in-gazebo-but-not-on-robot](http://answers.ros.org/question/218849/gmapping-works-in-gazebo-but-not-on-robot/)

When running

> rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link camera_depth_frame 100

my problems were solved.

---

Originally posted by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) with karma: 171 on 2016-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4